# return values from exceptions in multiprocessing

Tags: python, exception, multiprocessing

I'm calling a function `task(url, param1, param2)` that return either the result of an API call to url = `url` or the `url` name if the API call did not work. My `task` looks something like:

```
def task(url, param1, param2):
    try:
        make_api_call(url, param1, param2)
    except ValueError as e:
        print("val error")            
        return url
```

Now I want to apply `task` to a list of 100 urls and start `multiprocessing` them as:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def run_tasks(urls, param1, param2):
    jobs = []
    for i in range(len(urls)):
        process = mp.Process(target=task, args=(urls[i], param1, param2))
        jobs.append(process)

    ## catch error processes
    error_urls = []

    ## start processes
    for j in jobs:
        j.start()

    ## finish processes
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()
```

From the above `run_tasks`, how would I return a list of the `url`s that had given me a `ValueError`? I tried `error_urls.append(j.join())`, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two method to get result from the process.

Method 1. Use `list` from `Manager`. You need't to use lock to synchronize between process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def task(url, param1, param2, error_list):
    try:
        make_api_call(url, param1, param2)
    except ValueError as e:
        print("val error")            
        error_list.append(url)

def run_tasks(urls, param1, param2):

    error_list = Manager().list()    
    jobs = []

    for i in range(len(urls)):
        process = Process(target=task, args=(urls[i], param1, param2, error_list))
        jobs.append(process)

    ## start processes
    for j in jobs:
        j.start()

    ## finish processes
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()
```

Method 2. Use `ProcessPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures`. This method is easy to understand and less code.

```
from concurrent import futures

def task(url, param1, param2):
    try:
        make_api_call(url, param1, param2)
    except ValueError as e:
        print("val error")            
        return url

def runt_tasks(urls, param1, param2):

    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        result = executor.map(task, urls, [param1] * len(urls), [param2] * len(urls))

    error_list = [item for item in result if item is not None]
```

At last, from the description of the question. It's a IO sensitive problem. I recommend you to use `ThreadPoolExecutor`. When you do a IO operation, the thread will release the GIL to let other threads to run. For a CPU sensitive problem, you'd better to use `ProcessPoolExecutor`. And `asyncio` is another choice to do concurrent programming in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try the shared memory.  use this `multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Array(typecode_or_type, size_or_initializer, *args[, lock])`

You can define this in in run_tasks

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Array
lock = Lock()
error_urls = Array(c_char_p, [], lock = lock)
```

And

```
def task(url, param1, param2):
    try:
       make_api_call(url, param1, param2)
    except ValueError as e:
       print("val error")            
       error_urls.append(url)
```

as the doc of Array():

> The same as RawArray() except that **depending on the value of lock a
>   process-safe synchronization wrapper may be returned** instead of a
>   raw ctypes array.

So it is process-safe.  More about Array() can refer [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Array) , about ctypes(c_char_p)refer [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)